# Chrome Relative Link PDF

Tags: html, reactjs, google-chrome, pdf, gatsby

Uploaded a relative link to a PDF on my website, works for Safari but not for Chrome. In Chrome, it starts to load then just shows a blank grey screen.

https://epic-albattani-3613b0.netlify.com/

(Hit the download portfolio button)

Not sure what's wrong here...used:

```
<a href="/files/portfolio.pdf">Download My Portfolio</a>
```

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ea Gray,

I have the same [issue#10899](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10899) right now.

It's a Chrome bug with the service worker.

You can disabling it `chrome://flags/#enable-service-worker-servicification` or
you can host your PDF somewhere and link to it to work around until they fix it.